# How to set path of the image from database if no image is selected for updating in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

guys could you please help me out about how to set the path of the image already inserted from the database if no image is selected for an HTML file input while updating it in CodeIgniter.

```
        $config['upload_path']   = "./upload/";
        $config['allowed_types'] = "png|jpg|gif";
        $this->load->library("upload", $config);

        if($this->upload->do_upload('profile')){
            $uploaded = $this->upload->data();
            $done_uploading["file"] = $uploaded['file_name'];
            $finalize = $done_uploading["file"];
        } else {
             //Here need code for leaving the already set path of the image to same
        }
```

Comment: Do you want to display an image from your images directory into the HTML?

Comment: I dont want to update image if there is no image selected in the file input and remain the image path same

Comment: So you mean, if there is an image set in your local directory you want to show it else the path would be same, and you would not the show the user any image?

Comment: If `empty($_FILES)`, Simply do nothing and you already got the old path in your db.

Comment: You could provide the remaining code on what would you do with the image data, so we don't end up guessing